# IE 10 has unwanted horizontal scrollbar

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-10

There is an unneeded horizontal scrollbar showing up in IE 10, but not firefox. It only moves one pixel and covers up some content on the bottom.  How do I get it to go away? I tried making the content 99% wide and such, but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found some code you can add to your css and it fixed my scrollbar issue:

```
@-ms-viewport {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

This prevents IE from thinking the page is wider than it is.